# Add the values of each line of only one column from many files with 2 columns - shell scripting

Tags: shell, addition, lines

I have many files that have this structure that have two columns of numbers. And I want to add each line value of the second column, for all of my files, so I'll end up with only one file. Can anyone help? Hope the question was clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: I have not understood if you want to sum columns or lines. Suppose you have a file having two lines made of two columns. First line contains 10 and 11. Second line contains 3 and 21. What do you want to see in output?

Comment: you should include some sample data

Comment: For example,

file 1  
1   0.5  
2   1.  
3   2.3  
file 2  
1   0.4  
2   1.3  
3   2.1  

i want the final file to be:  

1   0.9  
2   2.3  
3   4.4

Comment: I still don't know how to write the lists, sorry for that, but each list that i wrote is a list of 3 lines with 2 columns.

Comment: @Joe I think I have enough information now...

Comment: @Joe please check my answer here below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is based on the information OP provided in his comments here above:

1. We have multiple files and we have to sum the second column of each of these files. As far as we know we could have hundreds or thousands of different files
2. The first column in each file seems not important and I'm going to assume (based on OP sample data) we have the same (first) column in each input file

The basic idea is to start with an empty summary (file `tot`), `paste` one after the other each file with `tot` and sum 2 and 4 columns (if present) into the second column of the new `tot` file.

In other words...

```
$ touch tot ; for f in * ; do paste tot ${f} | awk '{ if ( NF > 3 ) { print $1, $2+$4 } else { print $1, $2 } }' > tmp ; mv tmp tot ; done
```

I did test it with 8 different files and seems to work as expected.
Of course `for f in *` has to be changed in order to capture ALL and ONLY the files we want to sum.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I only have 2 columns in each file, but it is giving me the double of what is expected.

Comment: OK, think I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you want is the sum of all values of the second column of each file, it looks like a simple enough job for awk:

```
cat files | awk '{ sum += $2 } END { print sum }'
```

Comment: awk should be able to take multiple files as arguments directly, omitting the UUOC

Comment: OP said "...so I'll end up with **only one file**...". What this final single file will contain using your proposed solution?